# How to load text file into string using VB6

Tags: string, vb6, text-processing, filesystemobject

How can I quickly load a text file into a string using VB6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read data from a text file using VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873830/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-text-file-using-vb6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Public Function ReadFileIntoString(strFilePath As String) As String

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath)
    ReadFileIntoString = ts.ReadAll

End Function
```

Comment: Not working in VB6... clearly this is .NET or better

Comment: @SetSailMedia not true, this is VB6. it requires a reference to `scrrun.dll` (`Microsoft Scripting Runtime`)

Answer (score 13):

This is the fastest way to load an entire file in VB6 without doing it line by line:

```
Function FileText (filename$) As String
    Dim handle As Integer
    handle = FreeFile
    Open filename$ For Input As #handle
    FileText = Input$(LOF(handle), handle)
    Close #handle
End Function
```

Comment: Will not work on all regional settings. Just use the code from the VB6 manual as in my answer to [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873830/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-text-file-using-vb6/2875248#2875248)

Answer (score -2):

Here's one way to do it using the filesystemobject:

```
Public Function ReadTextFileIntoString(strPathToFile as String) as String
  Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
  Dim objTxtStream As TextStream        
  Dim strOutput as String
  Set objTxtStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPathToFile)
  Do until objTxtStream.AtEndOfStream
   strOutput = strOutput + objTxtStream.ReadLine
  Loop

  objTxtStream.Close
  ReadTextFileIntoString = strOutput
End Sub
```

Comment: Unnecessary looping through line by line. Don't need to close TextStream.

Comment: Using FSO is unnecessary in first place. Same for your answer.

Comment: @CraigJ: No harm, until some bogus uninstaller unregisters the COM server.

Comment: @wqw: then you use a self-heal MSI installer for your app - problem solved.