# VB 6 + Capture text from file and copy it to form window

Tags: vb6

The following VB 6 code saves text from the textBox in the form  GUI to file.txt (By the click on the button)

How to do the reverse option – copy/capture file text (file.txt) , and passed it on the textBox in the form GUI , I will happy to get real example

remark - (before passed need to clear the form window from any text )

```
  Private Sub save_Click()

    saves = (Form1.Caption)

    FCO.CreateTextFile App.Path & "\" & saveas & "file.txt", True

    FCO.OpenTextFile(App.Path & "\" & saveas & "file.txt", ForWriting).Write Text1.Text

  End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read data from a text file using VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873830/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-text-file-using-vb6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads from a file and puts the results in Text1.Text.

```
Private Sub save_Click()  
    Dim sFile as String
    sFile = "c:\whatever"
    Dim sData as String
    Dim fnum as Integer
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open sFile For Input As #fnum
    If Not eof(fnum) Then
         Input #fnum, sData
         Text1.Text= sData
    End If
    Close #fnum
End Sub
```

Comment: I get compliation error on line --> If Not eof(fnum) , do you know what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Eytan: yeah, I left off the Then. Sorry about that

Comment: another problem - file content not displayed in the text box in the form GUI ? , I mean file text not appears in the text box after click on the bottom its appears on the form title - I update my question about the textBox

Comment: @Eytan: This reads a single line of text, I'll leave it to you to handle if you want more than one line (hint: use a do while loop).

Comment: @Eytan, Your code sample also uses the form caption.  Do you *really* need help assigning a string to a Textbox?  To be honest, I don't even answer questions that basic.

Comment: Ok thanks allot about your great answer you help me allot, I was start to learn VB6 from this week

Answer (score 0):

You can load in the contents of a file using the standard VB6 file I/O operations

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim Size As Long
Dim Data() As Byte

'Open the file
FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Binary As #FileNum

'Read all the data
Size = LOF(FileNum)
ReDim Data(Size - 1)
Get #FileNum, , Data
Close #FileNum

'Convert to a string
TextBox.Text = StrConv(Data, vbUnicode)
```

See the [original article](http://www.earlsoft.co.uk/tips/fileio.php).

Comment: Shorter to use the method from the VB6 manual. As in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2875248/15639) to this duplicate question